# Why variable var is not referenced?

Tags: c, variables, extern, variable-declaration

**This is not a problem to fix or something.Just want to know the behaviour**

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern int var;
int main()
{
    var = 10;
    printf("%d ", var);
    return 0;
}
```

Here we can see that `var` was defined as `extern` and inside the `main()` function `var` was given definition. But when the `var` was outputted it gave an error

> undefined reference to `var`.

Then where does the value `10` go? Will it go to `extern var` or it is stored in a garbage memory location?

So what exactly happens during compilation at line `var =10` and the next line.

Compile Log:

```
Compilation error   time: 0 memory: 2156 signal:0
/home/PpnviQ/ccRtZapf.o: In function `main':
prog.c:(.text.startup+0x13): undefined reference to `var'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: `var` is not defined in the code shown. Just declared.

Comment: @Olaf what  exactly ```var =10``` means,it does'nt mean defining

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: I'm very confident my comment implied that! Was not me writing "And inside the main function a var was given definition" But maybe you mena something else. Please clarify and see [ask].

Comment: @GoogleBot It means *assignment*. You tell the compiler: There is a a variable `var` out there, let's assign it with `10`. Compiler says: "OK! Let's do it". And then comes the linker and says: "Hey guys, you told me that there is a variable out there, but I don't know about it".

Comment: @EugeneSh. can you explain interms of memory location(Taking a dummy address)

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/10077

Comment: @GoogleBot What memory locations? That's exactly the problem here, that there is no memory locations.

Comment: You should have `int var;` in another file. Extern means you define the variable in other place and you need to use that in this file.

Comment: @G.Emadi: `exterrn int var` is a **declaration**, not a definition! Please be precise when using standard terms.

Comment: the behaviour is that without a proper declaration there's not a memory allocation to hold the variable `var` ... thus the complaint of the linker...

Comment: @weirdgyn: And another one: There is a declaration! The problem seems to be the missing **definition**! But without more information, it is hard to tell.

Comment: sorry .. it was definition... got lost in the middle ;-)

Comment: @Olaf .. no need for further info.. I saw this type of error dozen of times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your code,

```
 extern int var;
```

is a ***declaration***, not a *definition*. So, in the complete translation unit, `var` is never defined. So your linker (*to be specific*) complains when you try to *use* it, (assign value to `var`).

Comment: the compiler is fine because declaring `extern` references just warn it to wait for a definition somewhere .. usually `extern` keyword is used to refer to variables declared in other units so it's normal that the compiler accept it.. probably you have a warning from the linker that found the reference left dangling....

Comment: @LPs thnx.. just fixed this! :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh what if i defined ```int var =25``` in another file and include it here.

Comment: @GoogleBot if you have the variable defined in some other translation unit which you're linking together, then your linker will be able to find the variable, and there'll be no issues.